# How to create and use buffer of structs?

Tags: vulkan

Directx provides [Structured Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471514(v=vs.85).aspx). What's the analog of this in vulkan? How to create one in application? How to use it in glsl shaders?

Comment: What is the difference between that and an ordinary array?

Comment: @krOoze What do you mean under an array? How would I access one in a shader?

Comment: Just normal array as is in C/C++. And also `struct`s. (GLSL have those.) Just asking if it is the same thing because my knowledge of DX is lacking...

Comment: Afaik, in dx I can use an array of structures with constant or structured buffers. They use different memory so the usage depends on the application. And iirc, there's no such thing as `array` in hlsl - I can pass data only in buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A D3D "Structured Buffer" is [equivalent](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/4432/2654) to a Vulkan "Storage Buffer", if that storage buffer is read-only. However, Vulkan ([like OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)) uses the storage buffer concept to cover a wide range of stuff that D3D considers different things.

RWStructuredBuffers in D3D are simply storage buffers that you declare in the shader to be writable. Append/ConsumeStructuredBuffers are just storage buffers where you bump an atomic variable to find the data that your shader instance is going to "append" or "consume".

At the level of the Vulkan API, these all utilize `VkBuffer`s that have the `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT` set. Even in the descriptor set, you need not specify whether a particular storage buffer binding point is read-only or read/write, or even write-only. How it gets used is decided by the shader, not the descriptor.